# Vertabelo - Warning: Reference Name seems to be invalid

Tags: mysql, sql, modelo-relacional

Estou usando o vertabelo pois preciso compartilhar meu programa com outros, porém quando trouxe meu trabalho para ele. Ele aparece os seguinte warnings, alguém sabe o que é?

link:
https://my.vertabelo.com/public-model-view/du31FQe6FjubhRlFTUREaNGTSb3ITgkZNMvQhr1iqHJzA1AVTsjA5RkZOEpCQgXA?x=3348&y=3219&zoom=0.7

o problema está nos comentários, a idéia é a seguinte:
Uma pessoa tem vários comentários porem cada comentário tem só uma pessoa responsável. 
Uma a noticia tem vários comentários, porém um comentário é de só uma notícia.

Espero que fui claro, obrigado desde já.

Comment: Tem um pequeno erro, a relação está 0..* quando na verdade tem que ser 1..* nas duas relações, ja corrigi, porém o warning não foi removido.

Outra pergunta é se eu ignorar esse warning irá perjudicar meu programa?